# Is there a logical fallacy for citing a single counter example which is not generally representative?

Tags: fallacies

Example:

A: buildings in the US are generally safe. Structural engineers have to stamp the designs before a certificate of occupancy is issued so you can usually be assured that there won’t be any concerns about the building’s structure failing.

B: Oh right, that worked out so well far (building that collapsed in the US). The stamp from a structural engineer means nothing.

B is cherry picking a single, non-representative instance of a building failing even though most buildings are safe. Their broad claim is not supported by their meager evidence.

Is there a specific name for using a single, non-representative example to support a broad claim?

Comment: This example sounds like an extreme instance of Hasty Generalization.

Comment: Your B names the [cherry picking fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_picking), in statistics this is also called [selection bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_bias) or [biased sample fallacy](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/logicalfallacies/Biased-Sample-Fallacy).

Comment: Whether it's a fallacy depends on whether you are being understood to be making a universal claim. If you are being understood to be making a universal claim then any counter-example is germane, and the proper response is to explain that you were not making a universal claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer you’re looking for is in the question you asked.

> cherry picking

From Wikipedia: “Cherry picking, suppressing evidence, or the fallacy of incomplete evidence is the act of pointing to individual cases or data that seem to confirm a particular position while ignoring a significant portion of related and similar cases or data that may contradict that position. Cherry picking may be committed intentionally or unintentionally.“
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_picking

Comment: Thanks, I think that fits the bill

Answer (score 2):

> A: buildings in the US are generally safe. Structural engineers have to stamp the designs before a certificate of occupancy is issued so you can **usually** be assured that there won’t be any concerns about the building’s structure failing.

> B: Oh right, that worked out so well far (building that collapsed in the US). The stamp from a structural engineer means nothing.

If A's argument was that a genuine official stamp proves that the building is safe, exhibiting just one example of a building which has collapsed even though it had a genuine official stamp would be enough to falsify A's argument.

So it all depends on exactly what is the argument.

Here, A's argument is essentially logical waffle because of the use of the word "usually", which only mean "most of the time", not "always".

Thus, given how the question is worded, A's argument is not that the conclusion is certain, only that it is probable. In such a case, exhibiting one case where the conclusion is false isn't enough to falsify the argument.

To falsify such an argument, we would have to show that the conclusion is not **usually** true, which is immediately more difficult because of the numerical ambiguity of the word "usually". This also makes A's argument weak. That an official stamp only usually guaranties safety means that we cannot really trust official stamps.

This is also why A's argument qualifies as logical waffle.

Answer (score 0):

A claims that buildings are mostly safe. He doesn’t claim that buildings are 100% safe. B’s counter argument shows that buildings are not 100% safe. But a single unsafe buildings doesn’t show buildings are not mostly safe - you’d need some number of cases.

If A makes some statement X, then it is legitimate to show that a similar but not identical statement Y is false, so people don’t make mistakes. That’s what B did. If B wanted to prove A wrong, it would be insufficient. If B wanted to point out the limits of A’s statement. That goal was achieved.